# Files Connect - External data Source Google Drive 401 Error: invalid_client The OAuth client was not found

Tags: google-drive

Following the SFDC help instructions on setting up Files Connect for Google Drive

1. Created the Project in the Google Developers Console as per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.admin_files_connect_google_auth.htm&type=5)
2. Created the Authentication Provider in Salesforce using the consumer key and secret as provided from the Google Developers Console project as per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.admin_files_connect_google_auth.htm&type=5)
3. Provided the callback URL from the SFDC Authentication Provider back to the Google Project
4. Ensured my user has Files Connect Cloud permission in a Permission Set
5. Set up the External Data Source for Google Drive, checked the box `Start Authentication Flow on Save` as per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.admin_files_connect_google_auth.htm&type=5)

RESULT, OAuth flow starts and error is displayed

```
401 Error: invalid_client The OAuth client was not found
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is quite simple ....

You entered the wrong clientId and secret in the Auth Provider fields shown here:

[image]

In my case, the Google admin gave me the key and secret reversed and I just blindly copied the key into the secret field and the secret into the key field. *Pro tip: The secret is always shorter than the key*

Don't forget to add the External Data Source into your Permission Set that you are using to enable Files Connect to Google Drive.

[Other possibilities in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205824/401-that-s-an-error-error-invalid-client-the-oauth-client-was-not-found)